# How to take panorama photo from ionic 3 camera

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, panoramas

**How to take Panorama Photo from Ionic 3 Camera**

I am building an Ionic 3 app where user can take a panorama photo from within the application accessing camera and the panorama photos can be viewed.

How can i access the Camera from the Ionic 3 Native cordova plugin and take the photo as panorama and save them in my app.

I have searched the internet but only i could find are viewers for 360 or panorama photos but no resource for how can i take Panorama Photo from Ionic 3 application.

I really need this done as soon as possible, If possible do let us know.

Thanks.